# Trying to pass a list to a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to pass a list as a parameter to a class. Should I be enumerating or indexing the list before sending it somehow?

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self,con,int,wis,str,dex):
        self.con = con
        self.int = int
        self.wis = wis
        self.str = str
        self.dex = dex

    def navigate(self):
        print("The player is navigating")

    def swing(self):
        print("The player swings and gets a random 
    swing score added to his dexterity")

    def heals(self):
        print("The player takes a restorative 
    tincture")

    import random

    player_stats = random.sample(range(6, 18), 5)
    player_1 = Player(player_stats)
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
    player_1 = Player(player_stats)
TypeError: Player.__init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'int', 'wis', 'str', and 'dex'
```

However, if I send the 5 attributes manually, as in

```
player_1 = Player(18,17,16,15,14)
```

The program accepts it without errors.

Comment: I’d advise against using `int` and `str` as variable names as they are overwriting the builtin types, in the scope of the class.  Might lead to unexpected behaviour later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `random.sample(range(6, 18), 5)` generates list, let's consider sample `[6, 13, 11, 12, 9]`. So what exactly happening is you're passing it as `Player([6, 13, 11, 12, 9])` while `Player(18,17,16,15,14)` is correct in the sense that each number is being assigned to placeholder appropriately in a way you had defined it.

Comment: I see. Thanks. The suggested thread included a solution that worked. Adding an asterisk * to the arg worked.

Comment: Yes thats true. I just pointed out the cause of error.

Answer (score -1):

```py
def __init__(self,con):
self.con = con
```

the con list will contain all the stats and you can access each one by using
self.con.(state_name)

or use dict as a good choice

Comment: what are you answering here?

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong.  It will not function this way.  `self.con` will *also* be a list. Why would it be anything else?